# P2P HDMI adhoc streaming device?

Tags: hdmi, streaming, tv, video-streaming

is there such a thing?

Basically I am looking for an HDMI dongle that would stream p2p between a computer and the hdmi dongle connected to a TV.

Chromecast only works if connected to a router with internet access.
Basically this device would allow your PC to connect to it directly as an adhoc network.

It would be nice if it came with it's own wireless nic usb dongle to connect to the pc (or mac) so you wouldn't have to disconnect your current wireless network to connect to this device.

This would be useful when visiting a cottage, friends place, etc without the need for chromecast (needs access to another wireless network), a cumbersome smartv addon,  or for HDMI cabling.

Answer (score 0):

There are those HDMI extenders that are network driven. Lenkeng is one of them.

They've also been reverse engineered, for those fearless that want to replace either the source or the sink with a computer:

http://hackaday.com/2016/06/09/hdmi-extender-reverse-engineered/

I haven't seen them with WiFi, so you might need to add a WiFi bridge with sufficient bandwidth.

As those use MJPEG under the hood, there might be a detectable quality loss. HDMI uses much higher bandwidth than simple Ethernet or WiFi can supply, so all those network based technologies use compression.

**edit:** Turns out they have a dedicated PC→network→HDMI device: http://www.lenkeng.net/Index/detail/id/73
Price seems to be in the $80-90 region.